# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Getting this error when trying to access my Market/Index, and I have no idea what's going on..

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'1<JuleMarked.Models.Market>', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'JuleMarked.Models.Market'.

The view is added from the controller and I've checked everything I can think of, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's telling you exactly what the problem is. You're passing a list of `Market`, when it's expecting a single instance. Try giving us an example of your code and we can help you.

Comment: Yeah, ThePerplexedOne is right. You might be passing in the results of a Linq Where() query, when you probably need First()

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a List of Market, but the model requires a Market.